# Wordpress new user email

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to customise the content of the email that goes out to new users when I add them to our wordpress intranet site.

It currently says:

> Subject: [Website name] Your username and password info Username:
>   "username" To set your password, visit the following address:
>
> `<https://"url"/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=....>`
>
> https://url/account-sign-in/

But I would like it to be a bit more user friendly (welcome to ... etc etc) as this is a new intranet for staff.

I have searched online but all the answers I have found are very confusing! How do I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `wp_new_user_notification_email_admin` filter hook.

This passes an array of arguments that you can alter and then you need to return the arguments at the end of the function. An example of this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email_admin', 'so_alter_new_user_email', 10, 3 );

function so_alter_new_user_email( $email, $user, blog ) {

    $email['message'] = 'Welcome!';

    return $email;

}
```

That will change the new user email to just say ***Welcome!***

[`wp_new_user_notification_email_admin`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_new_user_notification_email_admin/) hook documentation.

Comment: Thanks, where do I put this code? Sorry I am still quite new to Wordpress!

Comment: You can either put it in your themes `functions.php` file or in a new plugin within the `/wp-content/plugins/` folder.